# Protective film for iPad 10.2

Tags: apple-pencil

I have a 10.2" iPad with the apple pencil. As I need to use the pencil lots of hours per day, I'm a bit worried that the screen may deteriorate. I was considering to buy a protective film, and I have two questions:

- does it have a bad impact on the writing experience?
- if I don't use it, will my screen deteriorate in time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A protective film will have an impact on the writing experience. If it is enough to notice as "bad" is really subjective.

I don't think you need to worry at all about your screen deteriorating from the use of the Apple Pencil. After all the screen is made of glass, and your pen has a rubber tip. It's made for this purpose.

Comment: About the screen deteriorating, I have a first gen pro, have used the pencil for hours each day, no problems yet (about 4.5 years of extended use)